# Dependency project items are not recognized in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper

I have a solution with 2 projects:

- A class library
- A MSTest project

I have added the class library to the test project's dependencies, and it compiles and runs my tests just fine.

However, within the test project, there are no completions being displayed for items from the library, and the text editor area displays any references in red, as if the symbols are not found.

Naturally, the items in question are all `public`, and the test project itself works, so this is a VS problem, not a C# or project setup issue.

I'm using VS 2017 15.7.2 and ReSharper Ultimate 2017.1.2.